# find x such that series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n \sqrt{n}}{3^{n}}(x+3)^{n}
$$

tried with ratio test
$$
\frac { 3 ^ { n } ( x + 3 ) ^ { n + 1 } ( n + 1 \sqrt { n + 1 } ) } { 3 ^ { n + 1 } ( x + 3 ) ^ { n } ( n \sqrt { n } ) }
$$

don't know how to solve that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your step by ratio test we obtain

$$\left|\frac { 3 ^ { n } ( x + 3 ) ^ { n + 1 } ( n + 1) \sqrt { n + 1 } ) } { 3 ^ { n + 1 } ( x + 3 ) ^ { n } ( n \sqrt { n } ) }\right|=\left|\frac {  ( x + 3 )  ( n + 1) \sqrt { n + 1 } ) } { 3   ( n \sqrt { n } ) }\right|\to\frac{|x+3|}{3}<1$$

that is

$$-6<x<0$$

then check the limit cases $x=0$ and $x=-6$ directly.

Comment: $$
\left|\frac{(x+3)(n+1) \sqrt{n+1})}{3(n \sqrt{n})}\right| \rightarrow \frac{|x+3|}{3}<1
$$ don't get this step

Comment: Well done! You get it now. Bye

Comment: ? any explanation why it's $$
\frac{|x+3|}{3}
$$

Comment: It is the limit we can easily find factoring out $n\sqrt n$ from numerator and denominator.

Comment: generel question if i divide num and den with smth it's basically *1 yeah?

Comment: Yes exactly, providing that the quantity is not equal to zero.